# Validate Month input 01 and 1?

Tags: java, if-statement, try-catch, bufferedreader, verify

I need an int value for both inputs. Either the user write 1 or 01 for January.
So it does work for 1 - 12 but if I write 01 it does give me my own error Text. 
For me its importent that it is a int Value, I know that String is perfectly work.

```
private static BufferedReader input= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
private Output output = new Output();


public static String inputText() throws Exception {
    return input.readLine();
}

public int monatInput(String text){
    String monthNumber= "";
    boolean again = true;
    while (again) {
        System.out.print(text);
        again = false;
        try {
            monthNumber = inputText();
            int number= Integer.parseInt(monatZahl);
            int monthLength = String.valueOf(monatZahl).length();


            if (number<=1 || number>=12) {
                again = true;
                throw new Exception();
            } else if (monthLength> 3) {
                again = true;
                throw new Exception();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            this.output.monatWrongInput;
        }
    }
    int converter = Integer.parseInt(monatZahl);
    return converter;

}
```

I hope you guys can help me to validate this problem. I seen many post about a for-loop to generate 01 digit but that's a bit different then validate as user input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get your own error because you don't use the right input :

```
monthNumber = inputText();
int number = Integer.parseInt(monatZahl);
//-----------------------------^^-----------this should be monthNumber
```

---

Another thing, to validate your input you need just to check if your number is  between 1 and 12, you don't need to check the `lenght` 
Your month is wrong if it is `> 12` or `< 1` because the 1 and 12 is a valide month(don't check with `<=` or `>=`).

```
int number = Integer.parseInt(monthNumber);

if (number < 1 || number > 12) {
    again = true;
    throw new Exception();
}
```

**EDIT**

Note both :

```
int i1 = Integer.parseInt("01");
int i2 = Integer.parseInt("1");
```

**Give 1** a valide number

Comment: I need the length because if I try to type 01 it throws me the new Exception. Yeah sorry for that i just try to translate my Programm. But it still dont work I cant writh 01 - 12. It works for 1-12 but I need both function. I hope I can make my question clean.

Comment: @MonsterHunter.Dev it throw your exception because you don't use the right input another thing check my edit

Comment: read my answer carefully @MonsterHunter.Dev you have to check with `if (number < 1 || number > 12) {` and not with `if (number <= 1 || number >= 12) {` it will throw an exception if you use `01` this is logic

Comment: You right ok it works thank you. You help me so much.